# steps to install spacy (anaconda) package along with dependencies without internet for python 3.6.5 for prod server?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spacy

Can anyone help in providing the steps to install Spacy package? I am facing a lot of difficulties in setting it up without an internet connection. Facing a lot of errors. Steps would be really helpful.
As of now I manually downloaded the dependencies (whl files) and installed. `Spacy` package is also successfully installed. But when I tried to import I am facing the problem.

```
(base) C:\Windows\system32>pip install E:/PythonPacakges/spacy-2.0.16-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: spacy==2.0.16 from file:///E:/PythonPacakges/spacy-2.0.16-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.0.16)
Requirement already satisfied: preshed>=2.0.1 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy==2.0.16) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: plac>=0.9.6 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy==2.0.16) (0.9.6)
Requirement already satisfied: dill>=0.2 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy==2.0.16) (0.2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: msgpack-numpy in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy==2.0.16) (0.4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cymem>=2.0.2 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy==2.0.16) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: regex>=2018.01.10 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy==2.0.16) (2018.11.22)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.13.0 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy==2.0.16) (2.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy==2.0.16) (1.14.3)
Requirement already satisfied: murmurhash>=0.28.0 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy==2.0.16) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: thinc>=6.12.0 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy==2.0.16) (6.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ujson>=1.35 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy==2.0.16) (1.35)
Requirement already satisfied: msgpack>=0.5.2 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from msgpack-numpy->spacy==2.0.16) (0.5.6)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.13.0->spacy==2.0.16) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.13.0->spacy==2.0.16) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.13.0->spacy==2.0.16) (1.22)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.13.0->spacy==2.0.16) (2018.4.16)
Requirement already satisfied: cytoolz>=0.9.0 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from thinc>=6.12.0->spacy==2.0.16) (0.9.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.10.0 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from thinc>=6.12.0->spacy==2.0.16) (4.28.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from thinc>=6.12.0->spacy==2.0.16) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.10.0 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from thinc>=6.12.0->spacy==2.0.16) (1.10.11)
Requirement already satisfied: toolz>=0.8.0 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cytoolz>=0.9.0->thinc>=6.12.0->spacy==2.0.16) (0.9.0)

(base) C:\Windows\system32>python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import spacy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from thinc.neural.util import prefer_gpu, require_gpu
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc\neural\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._classes.model import Model
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc\neural\_classes\model.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .. import util
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc\neural\util.py", line 3, in <module>
    from preshed.maps import PreshMap
  File "cymem.pxd", line 1, in init preshed.maps
ValueError: cymem.cymem.Pool has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 64, got 48
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I went through the same, fixed it uninstalling all spacy related packages and files then reinstalling it to version 2.0.13. You can do this by-

```
pip install spacy ==2.0.13
```

For conda i suppose doing the same with 'conda install spacy ==2.0.13' should also work.

Edit - You can do this without uninstalling spacy aswell